# Custom ErrorTemplate off screen display of error

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am working on a WPF application and I have added a custom error template to all text boxes. My application runs in full screen mode. The error is displayed in a DockPanel docked to the right of the control (AdornedElementPlaceholder). However, if the control is already on the right side of the screen it causes the error to be displayed outside the bounds of the application.

I am looking for a way to check if the far right top/bottom corner of the ErrorBorder is out of the bounds of the application. If so then change the docking from right to left. I was thinking of using a converter of sorts on the ErrorBorder control. Here is my code for the ErrorTemplate.

**Error Template:**

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CustomErrorTemplate">
    <DockPanel>
        <!--ERROR-->
        <Border x:Name="ErrorBorder"
                Background="Red"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="1"
                DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                Margin="5 0"
                Height="{Binding ActualHeight,
                                 ElementName=ErrorAdorner}">
            <TextBlock Background="Red"
                       Foreground="White"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       FontSize="{Binding ActualHeight,
                                          Converter={StaticResource FontSizeConverter},
                                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Border},
                                                                         Mode=FindAncestor}}"
                       Text="{Binding ElementName=ErrorAdorner,
                                      Path=AdornedElement.(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}"/>
        </Border>
        <!--CONTENT-->
        <AdornedElementPlaceholder x:Name="ErrorAdorner" />
    </DockPanel>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Value="True">
            <DataTrigger.Binding>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BooleanToOrConverter}">
                    <Binding ElementName="ErrorAdorner" Path="AdornedElement.IsKeyboardFocused" />
                    <Binding ElementName="ErrorAdorner" Path="AdornedElement.IsMouseOver" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </DataTrigger.Binding>
            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="FadeInStoryboard">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00.15"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="ErrorBorder"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         To="1" />
                        <ThicknessAnimation Duration="00:00:00.15"
                                            Storyboard.TargetName="ErrorBorder"
                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                            FillBehavior="HoldEnd"
                                            From="1,0,0,0"
                                            To="5,0,0,0">
                            <ThicknessAnimation.EasingFunction>
                                <BackEase EasingMode="EaseOut" Amplitude="2"/>
                            </ThicknessAnimation.EasingFunction>
                        </ThicknessAnimation>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
            <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FadeInStoryboard"/>
                <BeginStoryboard x:Name="FadeOutStoryBoard">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:00"
                                         Storyboard.TargetName="ErrorBorder"
                                         Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                         To="0"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
        </DataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

**Note:** I am using this same error template for various controls within my application. So my objective would need to work with "any" control.

Also, here is how I am implementing my error template for all TextBox control's.

**TextBox Style:**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
<Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{StaticResource CustomErrorTemplate}" />
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <SolidColorBrush Color="Pink" />
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Simple approach***

For this particular case

Create one more ErrorTemplate with `DockPanel.Dock = Left` set in its `ErrorBorder`. Set some `MinWidth=200` in your both `DockPanel`.

Handle  `Validation.Error="Tb_Error_1"` in your `TextBox`, also set `NotifyOnValidationError="True"` in your `Binding`.

```
    private void Tb_Error_1(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        ControlTemplate template = this.Resources["LeftCustomErrorTemplate"] as ControlTemplate;
        double minWidth = 200; // This we set in DockPanel in ControlTemplate

        Vector tbofset = VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(sender as TextBox);

        if (tbofset.Length + minWidth > this.ActualWidth - tbofset.X)
            Validation.SetErrorTemplate(Tb, this.Resources["LeftCustomErrorTemplate"] as ControlTemplate);
        else
            Validation.SetErrorTemplate(Tb, this.Resources["CustomErrorTemplate"] as ControlTemplate);
    }
```

***Best would be to use a `ToolTip`***

Use a `ToolTip`. It is because of `CustomPopupPlacementCallback`, which allows you to specify various placement position array, and the framework decides which one provides best visibility to your `ToolTip`.

A `ToolTip` readjusts itself to always appear fully visible all the time.

[How to: Specify a Custom Popup Position ?](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743607(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: This worked perfectly. The tooltip readjusts if it goes off screen. Thank you!